# How to edit html of a wordpress page with syntax highlighting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing a site with wordpress. I studied the core and its operation very carefully, especially how a theme is composed and how to build everything from scratch. But there is really something that I'm missing because of my inexperience.

Let's say I built my theme, I have my header, my footer, my functions.php with all the shortcodes of my functions, the single pages templates of the articles and cpt etc .. At this point I would like to create some pages, designed from scratch like the home or the contact section. So.. I go to page-> new page, then I select the three dots at the top right and choose the html visualization. At this point I can write my html and build my pages.

So far everything is ok, but how can I work in this way? I mean I see a white small box with the code written raw, without any highlighting of the syntax or a tool bar with basic tools like search and replace .. in short, is very difficoult to write code without a minimal editor similar to notepad ++. It is really impossible for me to work this way. I searched if there are any plugins, but I could not find anything stable .. what am I missing?

Maybe custom pages have to be written in a different way.

Comment: The only plugin I found that can do this job is "HTML Editor Syntax Highlighter". But I think that I'm missing the correct way to edit html code in wordpress pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't be dumping huge amounts of HTML into the database via the content editor.

The content editor isn't intended to be your one stop shop to dumping HTML into the DB.

Your best bet is to read up on template-hierarchy for doing custom pages like the homepage. You can create individual templates for each page.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy

Regarding data, you can add custom metaboxes to pages to store that. There are also plugins like Advanced Custom Fields that make it easier.